# Как правильно работать с названиями файлов и в целом со строками?

Tags: php, архитектура, рефакторинг

Приветствую. Есть небольшой проект на php, без использования каких-либо фреймворков. В приложении много разных файлов, например: `settings.json`, `logo.png`, ..., а также множество php-скриптов. Еще приложение работает с базой данных.

Множество скриптов может использовать какой-то один файл, например, в нескольких скриптах есть строка `$s = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/settings.json');`. Или еще один случай, например, все скрипты работают с "захардкоденными" именами таблиц, столбцов.

Проблема заключается в том, что если я захочу переименовать файл, например, `settings.json`, либо поменять название таблицы или столбца, то мне придется вносить правки в целую кучу файлов, что очень неудобно.

Как в таких случаях правильно организовать работу с названиями файлов/таблиц? Интересует именно корректный с точки зрения архитектуры и красоты кода метод.

Comment: Для settings наиболее правильным будет сделать отдельный класс работы с настройками. И везде его подключать. Тогда получение файла по имени будет только в одном единственном месте, в этом классе. Что касается БД, то она должна быть полностью спроектирована до начала разработки приложения и в последствии уже не меняться. Разве что по мере развития могут добавляться какие то новые сущности, под них будут создаваться таблицы, колонки, но не переименовываться что то старое

Comment: @Mike, для настроек написать класс не составит труда, это понятно. Как быть, на ваш взгляд, в более общем случае — у меня не только settings.json хранит данные, есть и директории с картинками, и файлы, содержащие разнообразные текстовые данные. Предполагается, что структура проекта не должна меняться и жестко заданные везде пути — это нормально, или же здесь тоже есть какие-то изящные решения?

Comment: А все остальные пути - это те же самые settings, просто храните их в нем. Если кому то надо будет например вынести картинки на другой диск, потому что на основном для них не хватает места, он просто поправит путь в settings.json и больше ни о чем задумываться не будет. А программа пусть получает все эти пути через тот же класс настроек, как любой другой параметр

Answer (score 2):

Более подробно распишу комментарий от Mike

> Сокрытие информации - один из основных принципов и структурного, и
>   объектно-ориентированного проектирования. ... Почаще задавайте себе
>   вопрос "Что мне скрыть?", и вы удивитесь, сколько проблем
>   проектирования растает на ваших глазах **(с) Стив Макконнелл,
>   Совершенный код**

Эта цитата относится непосредственно к Вашему случаю, скрипты не должны знать название и путь к файлу, чтобы взять нужную информацию, поэтому действительно нужно сделать либо отдельный класс Settings, либо расширить файл config.php (в котором у Вас например лежат доступы к базе данных.

**В первом случае Settings**

1. Создаете отдельную таблицу в БД Settings, с элементарными полями
   `code`, `value`, `description`
2. Создаете отдельный класс Settings, который будет подключен ко всем Вашим классам или скриптам
3. Единственная задача этого класса будет заключаться в том, чтобы
   обратиться к таблице `Settings`, найти нужную строку по ключу `code`
   и вернуть значение `value`.
4. Таким образом Ваши строчки в скриптах 
   `$s = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/settings.json');` станут выглядеть
   примерно так 
   `$s = file_get_contents(Settings::Code('settings_file'));`
5. И теперь, когда
   Вы захотите изменить путь к файлу настроек, Вам достаточно будет
   изменить одну строку в базе данных.

В моем случае, на yii2 класс Settings выглядит так

```
class Settings extends ActiveRecord
{
    const CODE = 'code'; // ключ
    const VALUE = 'value'; // значение
    const DESCRIPTION = 'description'; // описание функционала

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%settings}}';
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает значение Value из таблицы Settings по ключу Code
     *
     * @param string $code
     * @return string
     */
    public static function Code(string $code) : string {
        return static::findOne([self::CODE => $code])[self::VALUE];
    }
}
```

**Во втором случае Config**

Наверняка у Вас есть файл, в котором прописывается доступ к Базе Данных, который выглядит как-то так

```
// Host
define('HOST_DEFAULT', !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? trim($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) : 'test.webstart.spb.ru');
define('URL_ROOT', sprintf('http%s://%s/', !empty($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) && $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? 's' : '', HOST_DEFAULT));

// Path
define('DIR_HOME', __DIR__.'/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', DIR_HOME.'image/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', DIR_HOME.'system/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', DIR_SYSTEM.'config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', DIR_SYSTEM.'storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', DIR_SYSTEM.'storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', DIR_HOME.'../log/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', DIR_SYSTEM.'storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', DIR_SYSTEM.'storage/upload/');

// DB
const DB_DRIVER = 'mysqli';
const DB_HOSTNAME = null;
const DB_USERNAME = '******';
const DB_PASSWORD = '*******';
const DB_DATABASE = '*********';
const DB_PORT = '3306';
const DB_PREFIX = 'oc_';
```

Добавьте в него строку типа `define('FILE_SETTINGS', DIR_HOME.'settings.json');`

И теперь Вы сможете в Ваших скриптах писать `$s = file_get_contents(FILE_SETTINGS);`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, использование файла с константами — это идея.

Answer (score 0):

В большинстве продвинутых IDE, например NetBeans, есть такая штука как рефакторинг. Например при переименовании файла в проекте он не просто переименовывается, а попутно заменяются все упоминания в проекте.

Если же говорить о столбцах БД и т.д. то я бы создал что-то подобное strings.xml (например такое есть в Android Studio). И в этом файле хранил бы строковые данные. И создал бы класс который эти данные представляет в удобном для использования виде. Например чтобы вызвать запрос к определенной таблице в БД:

```php
$db->query("SELECT * FROM ".$str->users_table.";");
```

Или можно внутри этого класса str ветвить строки в зависимости от назначения.

```php
$str->db->users_table
```